# LocationManager: is the "network" provider always enabled?

Tags: android, location

I want to select a LocationProvider that is enabled in Android. The project build target is Android 2.1.

This is what I do in onCreate().

```
// ...
LocationManager locationMgr = (LocationManager) 
getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
criteria.setCostAllowed(false);     

String bestProvider = locationMgr.getBestProvider(criteria, true);  

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),   "Provider = " + bestProvider + " enabled= " + locationMgr.isProviderEnabled(bestProvider), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// ...
```

Now, I switch each network interface off and set flight mode on my device (HTC Desire, Android 2.2). I disconnect the device from USB. There is clearly no provider alive who  could actually provide location data to the device. I specifically ask **getBestProvider** for enabled providers only, so I expect it to return null or an empty string in that case. I expect **isProviderEnabled** to return false.

The actual result is that **getBestProvider** returns "network" and **isProviderEnabled** reports it to be "enabled". Is "network" always "enabled" even when its not?

Comment: This might also be caused by Android caching network location, as it is unlikely to change soon because of the coarse granularity. That's just a guess though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some digging I can answer my own question. First I tried airplane mode with:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo[] nwInfos = connectivityMgr.getAllNetworkInfo();
for (NetworkInfo nwInfo : nwInfos) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Network Type Name: " + nwInfo.getTypeName());
  Log.d(TAG, "Network available: " + nwInfo.isAvailable());
  Log.d(TAG, "Network c_or-c: " + nwInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting());
  Log.d(TAG, "Network connected: " + nwInfo.isConnected());
}
```

The **ConnectivityManager** reports correctly "false" since there is no connection. This is useful to check if you actually have a network and therefore a network-based location provider available. Then I took a second look at my device settings. And here is the answer:

```
locationMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
```

reports if the user has checked the device setting (in my case under **Location - My Location**). If you uncheck all providers there it does return **null** as expected. It is actually documented in [isProviderEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String%29) but I must have overlooked it . Case closed.

Comment: `isProviderEnabled()` should return false in this example, right? You can't have a method with a primitive return type that returns null. Perhaps you mean `getBestProvider()`?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? On my Galaxy S IV phone under settings, I have set 'Permissions'-->'Location services'-->'Use wireless networks' to be TRUE. However, if I turn off everything (turn off GPS, WiFi, and cellular radio, and also enable airplane mode), then `isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)` still returns TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static boolean isLocationSensingAvailable()
{
    boolean hasActiveLocationProvider = false;
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
    for (String providerName:providers)
    {
        if (providerName.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        {
            hasActiveLocationProvider = isLocationProviderEnabled(providerName);
        }
        if (providerName.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
        {
            hasActiveLocationProvider = ( SpondleApplication.isOnline() &&  isLocationProviderEnabled(providerName));
        }
    }
    return hasActiveLocationProvider;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ollie. I should add that I know how to work around the situation. I am interested to get an answer if the result of **getBestProvider** and **isLocationProviderEnabled** are always like I described, i.e. if "network" is always reported as "enabled" even when it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You always get true as an answer because you have selected the "Use networks" option in the settings menu. I also had this problem until I found this out. I hope you find this useful.